# cocos2d-js integrate with SDKBOX IAP

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I am currently developing a game using Cocos2d-JS and using SDKBOX IAP [in this link](http://sdkbox-doc.github.io/en/plugins/iap/v3-js/)
when trying to compile or run my game i got error .. 
i hope help to resolve this issue .

cocos2d-js V 3.7
sdkbox-iap_v1.2.3.3
console : cocos run -p android

the error :

> Buildfile:
>   D:\test\MyGame\frameworks\runtime-src\proj.android\build.xml
>
> -check-env:  [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2  [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\azeem\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>
> -setup:
>        [echo] Project Name: MyGame   [gettype] Project Type: Application
>
> -pre-clean:
>
> clean:
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\azeem\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:459:
>   Failed to resolve library path:
>   C:/Users/zeem/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libp
>   roject/google-play-services_lib/
>
> Total time: 3 seconds Error running command, return code: 1.
>   D:\test\MyGame>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error comes because your google play services location is pointing to wrong one.

Please open your `project.properties` file from **proj.android** folder
and change the link to correct one.

however, the link is a relative path to the root of your project.
Please let me know, if you face issues in giving correct path.

Please go through these guides.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/guide-how-to-install-sdkbox-installer-to-work/24984

http://sdkbox-doc.github.io/en/